# How to calculate the surface area of a stepped surface slab in a unit cell?

Tags: crystallography, surfaces, atomic-simulation-environment, periodic-system, atomistic-simulation

I am trying to calculate the surface energies of Ni fcc (111) and (311) surfaces, therefore I need to calculate the surface areas. I use periodic slabs to model these surfaces. For a flat fcc (111) surface as shown below

[image]

the surface area is simply given by the norm of the cross product of the two lattice vectors of the unit cell. In Python code:

```
from ase.build import fcc111
import numpy as np
        
slab = fcc111('Ni', (4, 4, 4), vacuum=5.)
A_surf = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(slab.cell[0], slab.cell[1]))
```

However, for the stepped fcc (311) surface, the slab looks like below (top and side views):
[image]
[image]

How should I calculate the surface area for a stepped surface (assuming I already know the Cartesian coordinates of all atoms and the lattice vectors of the unit cell)?

Comment: The [OVITO](https://www.ovito.org/) package had a construct surface mesh feature which used to map the surface of the structure, and returned the properties such as surface area and volume. However I am not exactly sure about the accuracy or the reliability of the method.

Comment: Before adding vacuum, Check first whether your rotated system <311> is still fcc. use common neighbor analysis in ovito. once it is FCC cross product of two in plane vector of simulation box is your area (whether step is there or not). It must be periodic and represent same fcc system

Comment: If this question is about how to deal with steps, it may be worth pointing out that, for a corrugated surface, the effective surface area depends on the size of your probe (e.g. a molecule that tries to adsorb, ...). A small probe may be able to resolve corrugation while a larger one may not.

Comment: Shaun, have the comments been helpful? Have you figured out this question over the last 6.5 months? Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani It turns out that for stepped surfaces, most people (at least in my field) use the approximation of the so-called *cross-sectional surface area*, which is simply the cross product of the 2 lattice vectors. So that's what I end up doing.

Comment: Nice! Do you think you can write a self-answer to this question then? It will be helpful to future users, and will also help clear our unanswered queue which is now more than 300 questions long!

Comment: @ShaunHan Usually unanswered questions here at MMSE get closed once they get solved, since it's hard for us to manage an unanswered queue with 300+ questions in it. If you're able to write a self-answer though, we wouldn't need to do that! Even if it gets closed though, if you want to come back and write an answer or put a bounty on it or have someone else write an answer, you can get the question re-opened simply by asking for that in a single comment.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.